# Hacker Rank : Project Euler#1

Tags: c, algorithm, function

I am new to competitive programming and I did a problem on Hacker Rank. The question statement is as follows:

"If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

Input Format 
First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.

Output Format 
For each test case, print an integer that denotes the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N."

Constraints

1≤T≤10^5

1≤N≤10^9

I've written the following code which successfully satisfies 3 test cases and fails at remaining two.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int p,int n)
{
    int j;
    n=n-1;
    j=n/p;
    return (p*j*(j+1))/2;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long int n;
    int t,j,count;
    scanf("%d",&t);
  if(t>=1 && t<=100000){
        for(j=0;j<t;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lu",&n);
        if(n>=1 && n<=1000000000)
        {
                count=func(3,n)+func(5,n)-func(15,n);
                printf("%d\n",count);
            }

        }}
    return 0;
}
```

What is the mistake in my code. Why isn't it getting accepted?

Comment: It's not about competitiveness ...It's about finding the answer for a puzzle.
It may not be useful but solving the problem gives a lot of satisfaction.
So If you people can really help me in finding the mistake,that would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm behind func()?

Comment: @jarmod: It's a variant of the sum of all natural numbers up to `n` being `n*(n+1)/2`, only with step `p`.

Comment: I've used arithmetic progression in func().
We need the sum of all multiples of either three or five – but what about 15? 30? They’ll get counted twice. So,
(sum of multiples of 3) + (sum of multiples of 5) – (sum of multiples of 15)

Comment: What are the test cases that you failed?

Comment: It wasn't showing the test cases. It just simply says that my solution failed in two test cases.

Comment: I believe the result would eventually overflow...you should probably use unsigned longs everywhere...

Comment: You have made the input, `n`, a `long`. That's not necessary, as an `int` can hold all required input. The output, however, can overflow. Consider making `count` and `func`'s return type a `long`. (Or an `uint64_t`, for which you need `<stdint.h>`.)

Comment: @VanuAparna: Well think about what result you get from `j*(j+1)` when `j` is greater than 65536. (And you're using signed ints, so it will bite you even earlier.)

Comment: @BenjaminTrent @M Oehm : I've given an input of 10^9 and it outputs : 631780268 
No Overflow.

Comment: @VanuAparna, what if the test cases want the results from a larger number than 10^9? You yourself said you do not know what the test cases are.

Comment: @VanuAparna: That's what you think. Why not make all numbers that are part of your calculation `unsigned long` throughout.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent: As you can see in the constraints of the problem,the maximum value that it has to take is 10^9.
So every test case is below 10^9.

Comment: The real result for 1,000,000,000 is 233333333166666668, which happens to be 631780268 mod 2^64.

Comment: @M Oehm : I've declared every variable in unsigned long int and it still shows two test cases failed and the same output.

Comment: What is the size of your `long`? It might be the same as `int`, i.e. 32 bits. (I think that is true under Windows.) Make sure it is 64 bits wide with `unsigned long long` or with `uint64_t` from `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @M Oehm : I've found the mistake. Even though I was using long long int for variables. I've used int for func() which resulted in overflow. When I declared func() in long long int, it executed well. Test cases were accepted. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

You are indeed overflowing your `int` when returning from `func`. Also, your `printf` statement should be `printf("%llu\n", count);`

So, the return from `func`, `count`, and the local variable `j`, should all be `unsigned long long` and your print out should reflect that as well. You need to make `j` `unsigned long long` because of the arithmetic in the return statement for `func`(this is at least the case in VS 2013).